# SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard error at Step 8 - Failed to create sample data

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, configuration-wizard

I am trying to install SharePoint Foundation 2013 (built in database) on a standalone server (Windows 2012 R2) and getting errors at the 8th step of Configuration Wizard.

I have installed pre-requisites before running the Sharepoint setup file. Could someone advise me how to resolve this issue?

It seems like a permission issue, not a clue where/what is it.

I am getting the following error when executing the Sharepoint Product Configuration Wizard for the first time after the installation.

***Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type System.UnauthorizedAccessException was thrown.  Additional exception information: 0x80070005Access denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 0x80070005Access denied.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateSite(Guid gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMajor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionMinor, Int32 iDatabaseVersionBuild, Int32 iDatabaseVersionRevision, String bstrSiteSchemaVersion)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPContentDatabase database, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, String quotaTemplate, String sscRootWebUrl, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName, Boolean overrideCompatibilityRestriction)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()***

If I run the Sharepoint Product Configuration Wizard again, I am getting the below error.

***Failed to create sample data.
An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.IsProvisioned()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.EvaluatorModeProvisioning.SharedEvaluatorModeProvisioner.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.EvalProvision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.EvalModeProvisionTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()***

Comment: Please verify if you have followed all the steps for installation from this link: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx

Comment: Please see I have installed **Sharepoint Foundation 2013** on **Windows server 2012 R2**. I believe I have followed the steps correctly for it.

Comment: Check if farm admin account you used to install SharePoint is show up in the SQL instance.

Comment: I have installed the Built-in DB version. So, there is no SQL Management Studio to check this. Is there any way to check this Hardik?

Comment: If you find the solution than kindly post here so it will hep others.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a common problem and there isn’t one solution for all.**

Try below steps if it works for you

1. Logon to the SharePoint Web Front End(s). The Web Front End procedures described here must be performed on every server that participates in the farm.
2. To open Services, click Start, click Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Services.
3. Find the AppFabric Caching Service. Right click the service and select Start.
4. Logon to the SharePoint database server.
5. On the Start menu, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (ot 2012), point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
6. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand Services, and then click SQL Agent.
7. In the results pane, right-click any instance, and then click Start.
8. A green arrow on the icon next to the SQL Server Agent and on the toolbar indicates that SQL Server Agent started successfully.
9. Click OK.
10. Logon to the SharePoint Web Front End(s).
11. On the SharePoint Web Front End(s), navigate to the following if SharePoint Server: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\`
12. If using SharePoint Foundation the path is : `C:\Program Files\Windows SharePoint Services\15.0\Data\Analytics_GUID`
13. Locate the Analytics_GUID folder, ensure this is shared. If not share the folder with authenticated users.
14. On the Start menu, click All Programs.
15. Click Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products.
16. Click SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.
17. Execute the following: `psconfig.exe -cmd Configdb Create SkipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost`

Comment: I knew this, but there is no 'Analytics_GUID' file on the system. The correct path for this file is 'C:\Program Files\Windows SharePoint Services\15.0\Data'. So, I believe it has failed even before creating that file.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: I have already tried those steps with no success. SQL Server Agent stops immediately after starting it. Also I can't do anything with Analytics_GUID as there is no such file on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1. Open up the SharePoint **Central Administration** site.
2. Navigate to **Application Management** and click on **Site collection
   Administrators**.
3. From there you set your credential as the Site Collection
   Administrator for each Site Collection in each Web Application.
4. Run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard
   again. You'll probably get prompted as to whether you want to
   overwrite your default site or simply not create a default site.
   Afterwards you the wizard should finish properly.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The Site Collection is showing as 'No Selection'. So, it seems that the site has not been created.

Comment: Please verify if your user has proper rights(dbcreator, sysadmin) in sql?

Comment: I have installed the Built-in DB version. So, there is no SQL Management Studio to check this. Is there any way to check this Dikesh?